# Does Internet Explorer 8 support HTML 5?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html

Is there any HTML5 support in IE8?  Is it on the IE8 roadmap?

Comment: HTML 5 is still a draft. That means anything can happen to it. Its development could even be halted like it happened with XHTML 2.

Comment: Hopefully there will not be any IE after IE8 and no will get offended by such questions.

Comment: More then HTML5 is IE8 that is and will always be a draft!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

IE8 beta 2 supports two APIs from HTML5: [cross-document messaging](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#crossDocumentMessages) and [non-SQL storage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#storage).

IE8 beta 2 doesn’t implement the HTML5 parsing algorithm or the new elements (no `<canvas>` or `<video>` support).

There are also bug fixes that align IE8 better with HTML5.

Comment: so the answer is that for all fits and purposes, IE8 does *not* support html5 - just some randome bits and pieces of it.

Which makes using HTML5 (as in HTML markup, not scripting API's) moot.

Comment: If you want HTML 5 support in IE 8 then download the IE plugin called "Chrome Frame". It renders HTML 5 just like Google Chrome does! More info is here: http://appleinsider.com/articles/09/09/24/google_sneaks_webkit_html_5_support_into_internet_explorer

Comment: Chrome Frame [is no longer supported and retired as of February 25, 2014](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started)

Answer (score 72):

You can get HTML5 tags working in IE8 by including this JavaScript in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('header');
 document.createElement('nav');
 document.createElement('menu');
 document.createElement('section');
 document.createElement('article');
 document.createElement('aside');
 document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reference article where you found this? Thanks +1

Comment: Sorry, included it for my form validation but did not work. Is there any link where we could find out more about how to get it working?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my section element, I removed all the rest. Where from do you know this?

Comment: see http://www.developerdrive.com/2011/12/the-usefulness-of-the-document-createelement/

Comment: how about the HTML5 "download" attribute? :)

Comment: You could probably use JavaScript to implement a lot of HTML5 by just creating custom JS components (for the new form elements, you would have to bind in some functionality), but adding a SQL database isn't going to happen, along with some other HTML5 features.  I personally would just say, stay away from HTML5 for IE8 applications.

Comment: @BuddyJoe, see section "Using HTML5 elements in non-HTML5 browsers" on the MDN webstite here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines

Answer (score 43):

You can use [this IE HTML5 shim script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) to gain a basic level of support for the new semantic elements in HTML5 such as `<article>`.

Comment: Should point out that this doesn't help with certain JavaScript usages. For example, the following will not work:

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<section>test</section>';

We end up with div.childNodes.length = 2. I ran into the problem using jQuery and have been trying to figure out what's going on in IE.

Comment: Nitpick: the script is called "shiv" (as in hand-made prison knife), not "shim".

Comment: Well, to be totally pedantic, the author uses both "shim" and "shiv". The project is called "html5shim".

Quoting from http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/:

Common question: what's the difference between the html5shim and the html5shiv? Answer: nothing, one has an m and one has a v - that's it.

Answer (score 25):

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is also a great option for giving IE HTML5 rendering capabilities.

Comment: From the Modernizer homepage - Modernizr does not add missing functionality to browsers; instead, it detects native availability of features and offers you a way to maintain a fine level of control over your site regardless of a browser’s capabilities.

Comment: Can't believe this got so many down votes. +1 to reverse one of them. Modernizr may not add any functionality to the browser, but (along with lots of other useful stuff) it *does* include the HTML5 Shim functionality, which has been mentioned in other answers here, and has been given good scores.

Comment: Modernizer combined with polyfill (http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#polyfills) seems to add compatibility support for HTML5 features. JavaScript must be enabled, though.

Comment: Can't believe this got so many up votes. Modernizr includes an additional library called shiv which makes ie understand HTML5 tags plus modernizr includes feature detection but it has nothing to do with html5. So if you want ie to understand html5 it's MORE logical to use shiv since Modernizr would be overkill. Basically, Modernizr is NOT a great option as you suggested.

Comment: +1 for the answer and thanks! 
Re the upper comment - it does give support to old IEs to render the document properly, it may not give the html5 player functionality or the 3d rendering and ext., but for regular sites that rely on proper inheritance of the css styles and that uses the new html5 tags, it does its work perfect. It also fixes some issues with the rendering and extends a bit the css support: adding rgba() support and other stuff by adding filters, which eases the developer life - these trivial things that nowadays always must be written to cover the old buggy microsoft browsers...

Answer (score 17):

Does it support

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Yes it does.

Perhaps a better question is what modern web features IE8 supports. Some of the best places to answer that are [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/), [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/), and [browserscope.org](http://browserscope.org).

HTML5 means a lot of different things to different people. These days, it means HTML, CSS, and JavaScript functionality. The term is becoming a bit "Web 2.0"-like.

Answer (score 12):

Also are supported HTML5 [hashchange event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#handler-onhashchange) and [ononline, offline event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-navigator-online)

Answer (score 8):

IE8's HTML5 support is limited, but [Internet Explorer 9](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home) has just been released and has *strong* support for the new emerging HTML5 technologies.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 is still in draft spec (and will be for a loooong time). Why bother?

Comment: +1 The question is almost 15 months old and you’re the first who mentioned that HTML 5 is still a draft.

Comment: Good point. Why bother? It is not like helping the web helps Microsoft. Hence, Silverlight and a not-so great browser.

Comment: @Gumbo - The (first) C language specification was not completed until 1989. Would you have waited until then to use it? It had taken over the industry by then. Why bother? I guess that depends if you want to get the most out of what today's platforms can offer. Otherwise, why not just use HTML 3.2 or even 2.0 forever?

Comment: @Justin No. It’s also quite common that standards are just a record of what is actually already a de-facto standard in practice.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/) guide for all HTML 5 features across all browsers and versions, including future versions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to make IE8 understand/support basic HTML5 tags.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var html5Elem = ['header', 'nav', 'menu', 'section', 'article', 'aside', 'footer'];
        for (var i = 0; i < html5Elem.length; i++){
            document.createElement(html5Elem[i]);
        }
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288472(VS.85).aspx#html, IE8 will have "strong" HTML 5 support. I haven't seen anything discussing exactly what "strong support" entails, but I can say that yes, some HTML5 stuff is going to make it into IE8.

Comment: Well, IE8 is out and we don't see "strong HTML5 support" and Microsoft is not known for upgrading like other more modern browsers do so any "strong support" will have to wait for IE9, yet Microsoft has not said much of anything about HTML5 for IE9 either.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about IE8 and HTML 5 support here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/giorgio/archive/2009/11/29/ie8-and-html-5.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers here are about adding HTML5 capabilities to IE8 and other browsers. These are called [Polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) and my favourite place for finding those is [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).