# IE8: drag'n'drop files to a webpage

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

Is it possible in IE8 without using third party plugin like Java?

Comment: Here is an article that talks about how Gmail is doing it: [http://ajaxian.com/archives/drag-and-drop-file-uploads-in-gmail-using-just-the-specs](http://ajaxian.com/archives/drag-and-drop-file-uploads-in-gmail-using-just-the-specs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer : no

Long answer : [how to determine the presence of HTML5 drag’n’drop file upload API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311887/how-to-determine-presence-of-html5-dragndrop-file-upload-api-like-the-one-from)

Comment: +1 for the great HTML 5 link, the file uploading API is not supported at all in IE8 though AFAIK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5 Maybe in IE9 (sigh)

Comment: I know it is third party...but you can use Google Gears.

Answer (score 3):

That's a standard HTML5 feature, only supported by Chrome 4+ and Firefox 3.6+ so far. But as for IE8, expect it to be included (and working properly) by the next millenium.

Comment: AFAIK works in IE 10. You know, maybe it won't take that long until IE8 goes away... like IE6, which just took a decade or so.