# Catch location of file dropped on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I want to create drag & drop placeholder in HTML, that will catch the location of dropped file. I target IE8 and IE9, and thought that some simple JS can handle this, but not.

I tried many variations. First thing I soon noticed from my failures is that IE8/9 doesn't support "[file api](http://caniuse.com/#search=fileapi)", so all examples I was able to search for here at SO, can't apply. Then I tried to use iframe trick to catch file location, but it doesn't work on IE8, which supposedly works on IE9, but I didn't check.

Then I thought to stop hunting in the dark and ask more experienced what could be the way for drag & drop feature in HTML page on IE8/9, without using huge JS libraries?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652780/ie8-dragndrop-files-to-a-webpage