# Jquery throws IE specific error

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JWSaZ/

This works fine in Chrome/FF, but in Internet Explorer it gives an error in the Jquery file:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 23:59:13 UTC


Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 16
Char: 55207
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: You are using HTML 5 markup. Is jConstruct this thingy to make IE understand HTML 5 elements? I can't find anything related to that on Google

Comment: @Pekka It's my own code, it just turns data for a niche piece of software into HTML readable.  Is the problem here then that IE doesn't understand custom tags?  This is working 100% fine in every other browser.

Comment: @Tom See the 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5

Comment: @Pekka no luck, same error when I use shim.  Have you tried the fiddle?  There really is nothing in there unusual that IE shouldn't be able to handle.

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure - when I remove the `construct` and replace it by something else, it seems to work but there are other errors. However, I'm not sure whether this: `var jC2_events = $(this).html().split('\n');` is very waterproof in the first place, as the HTML could be altered by the user agent (e.g. by removing the breaks.) But maybe @Thomas' answer helps

Comment: @Pekka I broke the lines down to var jC2_rawData = $(this).html().trim();var jC2_events = jC2_rawData.split('\n'); but this doesn't have much effect.  I don't get any different errors by changing the tag (are you changing the each to match the tag change?

Comment: @Tom I did change the tag name in the each, yeah. Does jC2_events actually result in an array with meaningful data?

Comment: @pekka, yes it takes the data between the two construct tags and splits them by newline.  Each line is then split and parsed into HTML.

Comment: @Tom and you are getting results for that in IE? You tested it?

Comment: @Pekka No, even if I interupt the flow with alerts it throws the same error in the Jquery file before it has a chance to do anything

Comment: @Tom the `split()` operation is giving me an array with 6 elements in Chrome, and with 1 element in IE. There may be other things, but it starts to fail at that point, probably because IE's `.html()` doesn't take the `\n`'s into consideration

Comment: @Pekka ah ok, thanks.  Any way around this?

Comment: @Tom not sure... You could try `.text()` instead. Alternatively, maybe use a different splitting character, or a DOM element (like a table) to structure the data more safely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to jQuery needing to call the function `resolveWith` which contains a `try - finally` without a `catch` block.  Until IE9, this is not supported by IE and causes the error:

> Unexpected call to method or property
>   access.

Essentially, it happens when the IE javascript engine tries to enter the finally block. An easy solution would be to link to your own copy of the jQuery source and add an empty `catch` block to this function.

Alternately, if you do not have to use HTML5 markup, change your `<construct>` tags with `<p>` or a div with an id and change your jQuery selector and your issue should disappear since this jQuery function does not appear to be called.  See a working update of your example in IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWSaZ/21/

Comment: Thanks for the working example!  Problem is this is going to be used on lots of sites possibly, so I don't want to use a <p> tag incase those website are using p's in their markup, also this means I can't modify the jquery source.  What's a good alternative tag format?  I don't want to rely on people manually naming divs.  Another script generator I saw uses <pre> I think, is this safe?

Comment: `<pre>` is part of the HTML4 definition, so should be a safe workaround for the issue you were having.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is when you set the jC2_events variable. In firefox you get something like this:

System:Every tick:Set width to Y-100:#A comment:Set angle to Atan(Self.X-Mouse.X):Finish it #This is a comment Sprite:On event:Do this:Do that:Do something else Clock:Ticks and chimes:Do something:Do it again!:Add one

but in IE 8 you get an empty string. So in ff your for loop loops 6 times but it only loops once in IE and fails on the if statement. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've put an alert before that variable is set, but it still throws same error.