# Adding button to jQuery Mobile page shows blank page on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-7, jquery-mobile

I'm experimenting with jQuery Mobile and have run into a problem on my Windows Phone 7 browser.

Whenever I add a button to the page, either `<input type='button'>` or `<button>`, the whole page doesn't render in the WP7 IE.

When I view the same page in IE7 (using IETester) I get a Script Error "Object doesn't support this property or method" Line 17 Char 45703, and then the page doesn't render.

Here's the html that's generated for my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>
    iplan
</title></head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
           mobile login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    ello
        <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTIzNjAxMDE2M2Rk5Yr3L4N9Yyh0TZrUHAh3ZX6rJck=" />
</div>

        <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblUsername">Username</label>
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUsername" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername" />
        <br />
        <label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1">Password</label>
        <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword" type="password" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword" />
        <br />

       <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin" value="Login" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin" />

        <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2">Boo</span>
        </form>
    </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            &copy; 2011</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I remove that `<input type="submit" ...` the page renders correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Played around with this and got same result in IE8 as you are getting in IE7. JS error can be eliminated by using solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023674/jquery (I added empty catch to try-finally) but this only got me to the point of displaying an error free blank page when the button is included.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now. I think it is a CSS problem - the button is rebuilt by jquery mobile, and as soon as that happened, we get a blank page. Surprisingly this does not happen on the jquery mobile demo page... 
The only way around is to add data-role="none" to the button or input element.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  "data-role='none'" does indeed display the page, but then removes the functionality of the button.  Looks like I'll just stick with an <a> I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Turned out I was using an out of date version of jQuery.
Solved this by using the most recent version.