# Thumbnails side by side in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css-float, inline, thumbnails

So it's the common thumbnails side by side in IE issue, I usually solve this with this code but for some reason it isn't working, any help?

I am using some HTML5 stuff so I'm not sure if thats the reason, first time using?

```
    <aside id="thumbgrid">
        <?php $i = 0; while ($browndog_portfolio->have_posts()) : $browndog_portfolio->the_post(); ?>


            <article class="portfolioitem" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a class="popout" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-post-image'); ?></a>
                <p class="title"><a class="popout" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <p class="timecode"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Timecode', true);?></p>
            </article>
        </aside>
```

CSS

```
#thumbgrid {
width: 720px;
}
.portfolioitem{
float: left;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-right: 17px;
display: inline-block; *display:inline; *zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of IE, but versions < 9 don't support the new HTML5 tags directly. Check [Does Internet Explorer 8 support HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5) for details and workarounds.

Comment: it works in IE8 but not IE7. weirdly everything else positions correctly on the page in IE7 though?

Comment: I've got a code in there that downloads something for earlier than IE9 btw that should make it work, but yeah just got this very random issue in IE7 and below. so I'd imagine it's the CSS?