# Strange JavaScript Code Appearing in Form Validation Error Notification on IE 6-8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have an HTML5 form that uses JavaScript for the client side validation. If there is an error in the form, a notification appears at the top of the form.

**In Internet Explorer 6 through 8, there is a problem in that erroneous JavaScript code is appearing along with the error message.** It works seamlessly in all other browsers I have tested.

I have identified the JavaScript code that appears, as a function from one of the plugins used elsewhere on the page.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening, and why it is only happening in IE. I'm hoping someone with more experience can identify the problem.

**The page can be found at the following address: http://dev.abito.ca/contact/**

The form is on the right hand side of the page. Just click the submit button with nothing in the form in IE 6-8 and you will see the strange code appear.

The JavaScript code that appears is as follows:

```
function (S, aG) { 
    var K = this.length >>> 0; 
    aG = aG || 0; 
    if (aG < 0) { 
        aG += K 
    } 
    for (; aG < K; ++aG) { 
        if (aG in this && this[aG] === S) { 
            return aG 
        } 
    } 
    return -1 
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, I have identified the above code as part of the Shadowbox plugin which is found in the **[plugins.js](http://dev.abito.ca/js/plugins.js)** file, at **line 2683**.

Also, the JavaScript for the form validation is found in the **[script.js](http://dev.abito.ca/js/script.js)** file, from **line 498-676**.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: http://www.shadowbox-js.com/support.html The support suggests that it may be down to the DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: @SOliver - Hmmm, the link seems to say it would be an issue with Strict vs Quirks, and unless I'm mistaken, there is no version of the HTML5 doctype that is strict. I believe it is standards compliant by default. Am I incorrect?

Comment: IE 6 and 7 don't support html5  and according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5 thread, html5 support for IE8 is sketchy at best.

Comment: @SOliver - I'm using Modernizr which contains HTML5 shiv which is suppose to deal with said lack of support. Perhaps it isn't perfect. Why do you think my issue would be the result of an incorrect Doctype?

Comment: I was speculating based on what the folks at shadowbox.js have said on the matter.

Comment: @SOliver - From what I can tell, Shadowbox itself is working without a hitch. This is what is odd, because Shadowbox has nothing to do with the form and is used for two links on other parts of the page. I have no idea why instead of displaying only the errors that are collected in the array, it is displaying a completely unrelated function. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to test, but I think if you change line 661 of script.js to

```
for (var x = 0 ; x < data.length ; x++) {
```

it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so very much. That had actually crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure if it would make a difference. I'm curious if you can explain why `for-in` would be a bad choice in this instance?

Comment: for - in is matching not just the elements of the array, but also the `indexOf` function that's been attached to the Array.prototype object at line 2683 of plugins.js. Note that it's only attached if indexOf is not natively supported, which is probably why only IE6-8 are affected.