# I cannot see browse button in input file type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an input file type via javascript.

Input type file generated as I expected except I can't see the browse button.

I searched input file type css styling but all I see was how to customize

the browser button. Below is how my screen looks like.

[image]

normally, file type should be appeared as second one but I am getting first one when I

generate a file type in javascript. below is my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
.uploadForm{
type:file; position:relative;
}

#addBtn{
width:100px; height:20px;
}
</style>
<script>
function addMoreFiles(){
var fileForm = document.createElement('input');
var addButton = document.createElement('button');   
addButton.setAttribute('onclick', "addMoreFiles()");
addButton.setAttribute('id', "addBtn");
fileForm.className = 'uploadForm';
document.getElementById('uploadDiv').appendChild(fileForm);
document.getElementById('uploadDiv').appendChild(addButton);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="addMoreFiles()">
<form name="frmname" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./ViewPage.jsp">
file<br>
<div id="uploadDiv"></div>
<br>
<input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>
<input type="submit" value="upload"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show us the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fileForm = document.createElement('input');
fileForm.type = 'file'; // only <input type="file"> has browse button
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to view it correctly across Safari, Firefox and Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/MWtzh/

Is there any specific browser on which you are trying to use it?
Some older IE version including IE8 old versions don't support HTML5.
Have a look here: [Does Internet Explorer 8 support HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5)

Comment: I am using tomcat and eclipse EE. This code was not running on the browser so this might not the browser related problem. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Your question was "Browse button did not appear"? I guess I have not understood your question. Anyways that your query is solved, Enjoy :)

Comment: oh yeah... my bet. It is always hard to explain something in second language. I wish english is my primary language but.. oh well.. guess I should try explain as far as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Look Mr. Seho Lee

What i changed in your function named addmorefiles() is as below :

```
function addMoreFiles(){
var fileForm = document.createElement('input');
var addButton = document.createElement('button');   
fileForm.setAttribute('type', "file"); //by this we are setting type of button...which u missed to put
addButton.setAttribute('onclick', "addMoreFiles()");
addButton.setAttribute('id', "addBtn");
fileForm.className = 'uploadForm';
document.getElementById('uploadDiv').appendChild(fileForm);
document.getElementById('uploadDiv').appendChild(addButton);
```

I think u forgot to set attribute "type" for given browse button "fileform"

I have implemented it and it works...

You can also try by replacing your function with my answer....u will get which u wants

try it....