# IE8 Layout Errors with Current CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So my website is located at   but right now it is not displaying properly in IE8. I have added the following css where I used to have `display:inline-block` to try and compensate but it is not working:

```
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;
*zoom:1;
```

Is there a quick hack to get my items to comply, or am I going to have to completely redo the style with `float`?

Does IE8 not respond to css on HTML5 elements like `section`,`article`, and `nav`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using html5 elements and in your css you are calling them as ex.

`header div#header_left {float: left;
width: 350px;}` and so on. IE8 does not recognize [these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746162/410273) for the most part.

When I inspected the elements, what I saw was this. [image]

AS you can tell, IE8 is not even recognizing your css.

Suggestion: Use divs or get IE to recognize the tags ([several answers here that show you how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5)).

Answer (score 0):

After looking it up, I found that a lot of your HTML5 tags don't work well in IE 8. There's a simple way to shim IE8 so it recognizes those tags. You basically have short script that runs document.createElement on all the html5 tags you want to use.

Here's a link for the script and the css that goes with it.

http://www.nickyeoman.com/blog/html/118-html5-tags-in-ie8

Comment: So that is just one of the problems, and it does not answer the question as to why it is happening.