# Built a site in HTML5 and CSS3 and now can't be viewed on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I built a site for a small business and it looks great and they love it. Everything is fine up until we notice that older versions of Internet Explorer (8 and older) can't view the site. It looks completely messed up. I used Bootstrap which uses CSS3 and HTML5 elements.

What can I do about this? I don't want to remake the entire website.

Comment: Step 1: fix the issue, 
Step 2: ???,
Step 3: Profit.

Comment: @Mike http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289225/does-internet-explorer-8-support-html-5 - Some possible solutions here, the second answer in particular might be useful, but IE8 doesn't completely support Html5 and so you may be left with some issues.

Comment: No matter what you decided to do, you are going to have more work on your hands... That's why these things should be discussed with your client.

Comment: No, I'm not confused as to why it doesn't work on the browser. I understand why perfectly. Did you read what I wrote? I'm asking for a solution, not an explanation.

Comment: If you include an html shiv you will be fine but pertaining to CSS3, you would have to let me see what you have made with that because it isn't the biggest problem. You may lose some gradients and rounded border but, to me at least, that isn't life or death. A shiv is life or death for older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an HTML shiv so older versions can tell what the new HTML5 tags are. For the use of CSS3, you need backup images or something for older versions to fall back on.

[html5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

[How to use](http://css-tricks.com/html5-innershiv/)

[More current info](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)

HTML5 Shiv IS A MUST FOR OLDER BROWSERS! This is why your site looks crazy. Older browsers don't know what a `nav` or `header` tag is so it will not display any of those styles.

Comment: I did exactly what it said. I downloaded the file and uploaded it to the web server, added that code in my header.php file before the CSS and it looks exactly the same

Comment: Was it supposed to change at all? What do I need to do to fix the CSS3 problem?

Comment: Can you put a link to the site so I can see how your CSS is? I also added another link with more current Shiv info. If your client is concerned about IE users then your 100% best bet would be to just make the html5 tags into classes. CSS can't add styles to a tag it doesn't know. The HTML5 tags is what's cause the most problems but once I see your CSS I can help you further.

Comment: Josh, can I email you on the email found on your website? I'd rather not post the link here. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah that is fine and you are welcome, hopefully this won't be to much extra time for you.

Comment: Could you use the email address that is on my portfolio and not the form if you did. I need to rewrite the functionality for it and have disabled it recently. Thanks! If you did use the email address, I have not received an email yet.

Answer (score -1):

It depends... some CSS can be emulated quite nicely with css3pie, check www.css3pie.com.

But if it's not enough, you may have to convince your users to switch to Chrome, Firefox or Safari.